# From all the cones circumscribed on ball with radius $R$ choose the one with the smallest volume.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

From all the cones circumscribed on ball with radius $R$ choose the one with the smallest volume (cone outside the ball).

I know that I need to find the minimum value of a function of a volume of a cone depending on the variable $\theta$, which is the angle. But I don't how to obtain the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the semi-vertical angle of the cone is $\theta$. Then the height of the cone is

$$R+\frac{R}{\sin\theta}$$

and the base radius is

$$\left(R+\frac{R}{\sin\theta}\right)\tan\theta$$

Let $x$ and $h$ be the base radius and the height of the cone respectively. Then

$$h=R\left(1+\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\right) \Rightarrow \csc\theta=\frac{h}{R}-1$$

So we have

\begin{align}
\cot\theta&=\frac{h}{x}\\
\csc^2\theta-\cot^2\theta&=\left(\frac{h}{R}-1\right)^2-\left(\frac{h}{x}\right)^2\\
1&=\frac{h^2}{R^2}-\frac{2h}{R}+1-\frac{h^2}{x^2}\\
x^2&=\frac{R^2h}{h-2R}
\end{align}

The volume of the cone is

$$\frac{\pi}{3}x^2h=\frac{\pi R^2h^2}{3(h-2R)}$$